# Check if directed graph G1 is edge-induced subgraph isomorphic to directed graph G2

Tags: graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

From the literature I've reviewed, I've seen the following options:

1. Node-induced subgraph isomorphism checking: Using VF2, ISMAGS, etc.
   This approach however does not check for edge-induced subgraphs.
2. Edge induced isomorphism checks: Line-Graph Isomorphism while ensuring no delta_Y exchange occurs (Whitney). This technique was for undirected graphs, and I'm not sure how to apply it for directed ones, and also it is for whole isomorphisms, not subgraph isomorphisms.

I would like to find an algorithm that will check whether a given directed graph is edge-induced subgraph isomorphic to another directed graph

As an alternative, finding the Connected Most Common Edge Subgraph might also help.